# How to forward declare a structure used as a member variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

I have a struct called `CardState` defined in **Application.h**:

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <Session.h> // Note that both files include each others

struct CardState {
    bool property1;
    bool property2;
};

class Application : public QApplication {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit Application(int argc, char *argv[]);

}
```

I then use this `CardState` type in a different file:

```
#ifndef SESSION_H
#define SESSION_H

#include <Application.h>

struct CardState;

class Session : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    void setCardState(const CardState& cardState);
    CardState cardState() const;

private:

    CardState cardState_;

};

}
#endif // SESSION_H
```

At the time **Session.h** is included it seems that **Application.h** has not yet been included so I need to forward declare the struct (see above). However, this is not enough, after having added the forward declaration, I still get this error:

```
'Session::cardState_' uses undefined struct 'CardState'
```

Which, if I understand correctly, means that the compiler doesn't know how to initialize my variable since `CardState` is only partially declared. I know I can fix this by making CardState a pointer, and that's usually what I do, but is there any other, more proper way, to fix this?

Comment: This doesn't make sense!  The first thing you do in `Session.h` is include `Application.h`, so why would you need to forward-declare `CardState`?

Comment: you probably need to #include "Application.h" and not `#include <Application.h>` [unless you put it in the standard library]

Comment: @amit: True.  But usually this works anyway.  If it didn't work, the error message would be "couldn't find header" or something similar.

Comment: Did you tried `extern struct CardState;` in forward declaration ?

Comment: @Oli: this is why it is a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @Oli: Well if I don't forward declare it, it doesn't work. For information, there are far more include statements in both files but I tried to make a simple example. Also I tried declaring it as "CardState cardState_" and I get the above error message. I also tried "CardState* cardState_" and it does work. This is usually how fix this kind of error but that doesn't seem "proper". So I want to know how people who have a clue (unlike me) do.

Comment: @Ican: `extern` applies to variables, not types.

Comment: Sure.  But there should be no need to forward-declare here, so either the error message you've posted doesn't apply to the code you've posted, or the cause is what @amit mentioned.  But then you should see a different error message.

Comment: Ok I know why - the problem is that Application.h includes Session.h and Session.h also includes Application.h, so forward declaration is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Oli Charlesworth's comment, this should work as it is.

In general case, you would want to either:

- Put `CardState` in its own header and then #include it in all "client" headers, thus avoiding any complications that might arise from include order of these headers.
- Declare `Session::cardState_` as a (smart) pointer and avoid need for actual `CardState` declaration.

-- EDIT ---

Now that you edited the code, it is clear that there are circular include dependencies after all, in which case your code really isn't going to work, so you must apply one of the solutions above.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up putting `CardState` in its own header.

Answer (score 1):

OK. First off, you don't need to forward declare anything here, because the struct you need is fully declared in that header file.

When you try to do it anyway, you end up getting an error, probably because the compiler thinks you are declaring a new version of `CardState`, and then it never gets the full declaration anywhere.

What you need to do is remove that second (stub) delcaration for `CardState`, and then fix the error that led you to (mistakenly) put that stub declaration in.

In the comments you say that original error message was something like "couldn't find header". To me that means you probably don't have the directory containing `Application.h` in you compiler's standard search library. You can add it with a `-I dirname` directive on the command line if you like. But most likely it is in the same directory as your other include file, and you can just change your include statement to the following and it will be found:

```
#include "Application.h"  // Note quotes instead of <>
```

---

**Update**: Laurent updates the example code, and specifically asked in the comments below about pointers.

First off, even in the updated code, I see no reason why the forward declaration is requred. Simply move `CardState`'s declaration into Session.h, and the problem would go away. Moving code around like this should always be your first solution. Forward references are really only *required* when you have mutually-referencing structures.

If you do indeed have mutually-referenceing structures, then yes, you will have to make at least one of those fields either a pointer or a reference. This isn't really for the compiler so much as it is so that its physically possible to implement the structure(s). If `A` physically contains a full copy of a `B` and `B` physically contains a full copy of an `A`, then your structure would logically be of infinite size!

Comment: I updated my code. The problem is that both files include each others, so forward declaration is needed. In that kind of situation, do I have to make cardState_ a pointer or is there any other solution?

Comment: @Laurent - Yes, but *why* did you do that? I see nothing in your first header that actually depends on your second header.

Comment: The headers are rather big and I tried to make the examples as simple as possible. Since this post, I try to avoid circular references as much as I can.

Comment: @Laurent - I did figure this was a much shortened example of something. However, if you got the interrelationship of the two classes right (they are **not** mutually referencing). Then it really should just be an issue of class placement. Move things around (possibly creating a new higher-level include file even), and the issue should go away.

Answer (score 1):

You are having circular dependencies, Circular dependencies are solved by using forward declarations.

Once you forward declare the compiler only knows that the type exists; it does not have any information about its size, members, or methods. it is called an **Incomplete type**. Therefore, you cannot use this type(Incomlpete type) to declare a member, or a base class, since the compiler would need to know the layout of the type.

So Yes, You will have to make the Incomplete type a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just wanted the confirmation of that. I was just hoping there was a different solution besides declaring it as a pointer or putting the declaration in its own header.